# laravel array_push is returning null instead of array first arguement

Tags: php, laravel

i have flashMessage trait which controllers flashing messages

```
  Trait FlashMessages
{
    protected $errorMessages = [];

    protected $infoMessages = [];

    protected $successMessages = [];

    protected $warningMessages = [];


    /**
     * @param $message
     * @param $type
     */
    protected function setFlashMessage($message, $type)
    {
        $model = 'infoMessages';

        switch ($type) {
            case 'info' : {
                $model = 'infoMessage';
            }
                break;
            case 'error' : {
                $model = 'errorMessages';
            }
                break;
            case 'success' : {
                $model = 'successMessages';
            }
                break;
            case 'warning' : {
                $model = 'warningMessages';
            }
                break;
        }

        if (is_array($message)) {
            foreach ($message as $key => $value) {
                array_push($this->$model, $value);
            }
        } else array_push($this->$model, $message);
    }

    public function getFlashMessages(): array
    {
        return [
            'error' => $this->errorMessages,
            'info' => $this->infoMessages,
            'success' => $this->successMessages,
            'warning' => $this->warningMessages,
        ];
    }

    public function showFlashMessages()
    {
        session()->flash('error', $this->errorMessages);
        session()->flash('info', $this->infoMessages);
        session()->flash('success', $this->successMessages);
        session()->flash('warning', $this->warningMessages);
    }
}
```

so i include it in my BaseController.php which its source is as follows.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    use FlashMessages;
    protected $data = null;

    protected function setPageTitle($title, $subTitle)
    {
        view()->share(['pageTitle' => $title, 'subTitle' => $subTitle]);
    }

    protected function showErrorPage($errorCode = 404, $message = null)
    {
        $data['message'] = $message;
        return response()->view('errors.'.$errorCode, $data, $errorCode);
    }

    protected function responseJson($error = true, $responseCode = 200, $message = [], $data = null): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json([
            'error'         =>  $error,
            'response_code' => $responseCode,
            'message'       => $message,
            'data'          =>  $data
        ]);
    }

    protected function responseRedirect($route, $message, $type = 'info', $error = false, $withOldInputWhenError = false): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    {
        $this->setFlashMessage($message, $type);
        $this->showFlashMessages();

        if ($error && $withOldInputWhenError) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
        }

        return redirect()->route($route);
    }

    protected function responseRedirectBack($message, $type = 'info'): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    {
        $this->setFlashMessage($message, $type);
        $this->showFlashMessages();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

and my GalleryController extends Basecontroller and store method is as follows for storing new gallery

```
public function store(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    {
        //        dd($request->all());
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'city_id' => 'required|integer',
        ]);

        //create new gallery instance
        //        dd($request);
        $gallery = new Gallery();
        $gallery->name = $request->name;
        $gallery->address = $request->address;
        $gallery->city_id = $request->city_id;
        $gallery->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
        //        dd($gallery);
        //        dump($request->toArray());
        $gallery->save();

        if (!$gallery) {
            return $this->responseRedirectBack('Error occured while creating Gallery');
        }
        return $this->responseRedirect('galleries.index', 'New Gallery added');
    }
```

lastly i included in my index.blade.php file with flash.blade.php partial which its source code is

```
@php
    $errors = Session::get('error');
    $messages = Session::get('success');
    $info = Session::get('info');
    $warnings = Session::get('warning');
@endphp
@if ($errors) @foreach($errors as $key => $value)
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Error!</strong> {{ $value }}
    </div>
@endforeach @endif

@if ($messages) @foreach($messages as $key => $value)
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Success!</strong> {{ $value }}
    </div>
@endforeach @endif

@if ($info) @foreach($info as $key => $value)
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Info!</strong> {{ $value }}
    </div>
@endforeach @endif

@if ($warnings) @foreach($warnings as $key => $value)
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> {{ $value }}
    </div>
@endforeach @endif
```

but when i try to save new gallery it is returning an error in flashMessage.php trait file line 46 which is as follows.

```
 if (is_array($message)) {
            foreach ($message as $key => $value) {
                array_push($this->$model, $value);
            }
        } else array_push($this->$model, $message);
```

the error code is comming from else block. so how can i fix this? this code worked with my city controller but not working with this GalleryController. i know ther error is array_push is expecting that the first argument should be an array. but but it says in else bock that $this->$model is null, why as it worked with my other controller, plz help
thanks.

Comment: `$model = 'infoMessage';` is this a typo? isn't it supposed to be `infoMessages`

Comment: @Kevin yeah it is working when i changed infoMessage into infoMessages, yeah right that was a typo. it worked.